# Setting color of JScrollPane

Tags: java, swing, colors

I have a JScrollPane:

[image: JScrollPane]

Is there any way I can colorize the parts of the scrollpane? Something like this:

[image: Colorized JScrollPane]

I'm using the Nimbus look & feel.

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23037433/changing-the-thumb-color-and-background-color-of-a-jscrollpane

Comment: For some reason, that only worked for me when I used the basic ui, not the synth ui.